# Regex to get all javascript tags c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will allow me to get all javscript and css link tags in a string so that I can strip certain tags from a DotNetNuke (Yeah I know.... ouch!) page on an overridden render event.

I know about the html agility pack i've even read [Jeff Atwoods blog entry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) but unfortunately I don't have the luxury of a 3rd party library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit, I gave this a try to get a javascript entry but it didn't work. Regex's are a dark art to me.

```
updatedPageSource = Regex.Replace(
pageSource, 
String.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\".*?{0}\"></script>",
 name), "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Don't do it! `Regex == ouch`!

Comment: "unfortunately I don't have the luxury of a 3rd party library." Care to explain why?

Comment: @marcog I'm working on a project that has to be finished today. If I introduce a 3rd party solution I have to get it checked etc to see if it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few comments on this, your RegEx is close, the following has been tested to work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".*myfile.js"></script>
```

I used the following test inputs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/myfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/Looky/myfile.js"></script>
```

However, I would caution on this approach, and it does take time to parse, can be error prone, etc...

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: Regex + HTML = ouch!

Your problem may be that you are not escaping the Regex metacharacters from `name` (e.g. the dot metacharacter '.'). You may want to try this:

```
updatedPageSource = Regex.Replace(
    pageSource, 
    String.Format("<script\\s+type=\"text/javascript\"\\s+src=\".*?{0}\"\\s*>\\s*</script>", Regex.Escape(name)),
    "",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Just one of the many reasons why you don't mix Regex with HTML:
updatedPageSource = Regex.Replace(
    updatedPageSource, 
    String.Format("<script\\s+src=\".*?{0}\"\\s+type=\"text/javascript\"\\s*>\\s*</script>", Regex.Escape(name)),
    "",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I also added optional whitespace here and there.

Comment: Watch out for the greedy `.*` in your code. That will match all the way to the last `</script>` tag it can find. You want `.*?`.

Comment: Thanks, we learn something new every day. For reference: [Regex: Greedy vs Lazy](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/935/regex-greedy-vs-lazy)

Comment: Oh...and your `\s` needs to be doubly escaped. Either that, or use `@"..."`, but then you'll have to escape the `"` by doubling them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to account for things like whitespace, other attributes, different orders of attributes (i.e. `src="foo" type="bar"` vs `type="bar" src="foo"`), and `"` vs `'` quoting. Maybe this?

```
@"<\s*script\b.*?\bsrc=(""|').*?{0}\1\b.*?(/>|>\s*</\s*script\s*>)"
```

I went ahead and took out the `type` attribute. If you have the filename, you know what type of script it is anyway; plus, this accounts for tags where the `src` tag comes first, or they used the deprecated `language` tag, or they omitted `type` altogether (it's supposed to be there, but it isn't always). Note that I'm using the lazy `.*?` so that it doesn't match all the way to the last `</script>` in the page.